# Application of wavelet analysis in computer science

Tags: computer-science, machine-learning, data-analysis, turing-machines, wavelets

I am doing research in computer science (data mining), do you think wavelet analysis is useful for me?

Comment: Wavelet is one of many tools you should be aware of; it'd be good to know enough to be able to understand when Wavelets might be useful.  Wavelets fit naturally over certain types of data, but not others.

Comment: Yeah, so for data mining (text & image) do you think it will be useful?

Comment: Image – definitely! Text, maybe not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refer to [A Survey on Wavelet Applications in Data Mining](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/pierre.borgnat/MASTER2/wavelet_DM.pdf).

Comment: I read this paper before, but i am not sure of the course (wavelet analysis) if it's useful for me to take or not.

Comment: Thank you, but i know this, i need book if you can bring me one for computer science major.